# Does every culture have a deluge myth?

Tags: comparative, flood-myth

A deluge myth is a story of a big flood that kills everyone. A few examples:

- Noah's Ark
- The story of Deucalion
- The flood in the epic of Gilgamesh
- The story of Bergelmir

... and so on. Is there a mythology without a deluge myth?

Comment: Egyptian and Japanese mythology?

Comment: I know for a fact that Egypt does

Comment: Really? I didn't know! Cld you tell me what it is?

Comment: Let us take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48013/for-bleh-and-k)

Comment: @Gibet what do you mean by "compulse"? That isn't a word.

Comment: What abt Slavic mythology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does every *culture* have some sort of deluge myth? Possibly, but it is impossible to say for sure. Major culture systems are a different matter. For example, if we combine all North American Indian cultures together, there are definitely some deluge myths, where as it would be hard to say for sure if exactly every single Native Tribe believed this specific myth or not.

> A flood myth or deluge myth is a narrative in which a great flood, usually sent by a deity or deities, destroys civilization, often in an act of divine retribution. Parallels are often drawn between the flood waters of these myths and the primeval waters found in certain creation myths, as the flood waters are described as a measure for the cleansing of humanity, in preparation for rebirth. Most flood myths also contain a culture hero, who "represents the human craving for life".
>
> The flood myth motif is found among many cultures as seen in the Mesopotamian flood stories, Deucalion in Greek mythology, the Genesis flood narrative, the Hindu texts from India, Bergelmir in Norse Mythology, in the lore of the K'iche' and Maya peoples in Mesoamerica, the Lac Courte Oreilles Ojibwa tribe of Native Americans in North America, the Muisca, and Cañari Confederation, in South America. - [Flood myth (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_myth)

Most of the following list is taken from this site: [The Talk Origins Archive.](http://www.talkorigins.org/) Although I have not put forth an exhaustive list of which cultures have some sort of *Deluge Myth*, it would be safe to say that a culture that did not have such a myth or legend would in deed be difficult to track down. Does one exist? Possibly, but we may never known. The Following list is only a small sample of cultures having a Deluge Myth:

**North American Native Indian Deluge Myths**

- [THE GREAT FLOOD](http://www.ilhawaii.net/~stony/lore126.html)  Ottawa Native American Indian Lore
- [North American Indian Legends: The Deluge](http://www.firstpeople.us/FP-Html-Legends/TheDeluge-Cherokee.html) A Cherokee Legend
- [Mexico](http://nwcreation.net/noahlegends.html#anchor490120) The Toltec natives have a legend telling that the original creation lasted for 1716 years, and was destroyed by a flood and only one family survived.
- [Eskimo (Orowignarak, Alaska):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A great inundation, together with an earthquake, swept the land so rapidly that only a few people escaped in their skin canoes to the tops of the highest mountains.

**Mesoamerican Flood Myths**

- [Native flood myths of pre-Columbian origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoamerican_flood_myths)

**South American Native Indian Deluge Myths**

- [Urcocari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%B1ari) Cañari People Legend
- [Unu Pachakuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unu_Pachakuti) Inca Myth

**Europe**

- [Greek Myth:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Zeus sent a flood to destroy the men...
- [Arcadian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Dardanus, first king of Arcadia, was driven from his land by a great flood...
- [Samothrace:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The sea rose when the barriers dividing the Black Sea from the Mediterranean burst...
- [Roman:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Ovid, book 1
- [Scandinavian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Sturluson, p. 35
- [Lithuanian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) From his heavenly window, the supreme god Pramzimas ...
- [Transylvanian Gypsy:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Men once lived forever and knew no troubles...
- [Turkey:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Iskender-Iulcarni ...

**Near East**

- [Sumerian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The gods had decided to destroy mankind...
- [Egypt:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) People have become rebellious...
- [Babylonian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Dalley, pp. 23-35
- [Assyrian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The gods, led by Enlil, agreed to cleanse the earth ...
- [Chaldean:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The god Chronos in a vision warned Xisuthrus, the tenth king of Babylon, of a flood ...
- Hebrew: [Genesis 6-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen%206-9)
- Islamic: [Koran 11:25-48](http://www.islamicity.com/mosque/QURAN/11.htm#25)
- [Persian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) In early times, the earth was full of malign creatures...
- [Zoroastrian:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Yima, under divine superintendence...

**Africa**

- [Cameroon:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) As a girl was grinding flour, a goat came to lick it...
- [Masai (East Africa):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Tumbainot, a righteous man, had a wife named Naipande and three sons...
- [Komililo Nandi:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Ilet, the spirit of lightning, came to live, in human form, in a cave high on the mountain named Tinderet...
- [Kwaya (Lake Victoria):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The ocean was once enclosed in a small pot kept by a man and his wife...
- [Southwest Tanzania (Rukwa Region):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The rivers began flooding...
- [Lower Congo:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The sun once met the moon and threw mud at it, making it dimmer...
- [Yoruba (southwest Nigeria):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A god, Ifa, tired of living on earth and went to dwell in the firmament with Obatala...
- [Efik-Ibibio (Nigeria):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The sun and moon are man and wife, and their best friend was flood...
- [Ekoi (Nigeria):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The first people Etim 'Ne (Old Person) and his wife Ejaw came to earth from the sky...
- [Mandingo (Ivory Coast):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A charitable man gave away everything he had to the animals...

**Asia**

- [Vogul:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) After seven years of drought, the Great Woman said to the Great Man that rains had come elsewhere...
- [Samoyed (north Siberia):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Seven people were saved in a boat from a flood...
- [Yenisey-Ostyak (north central Siberia):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Flood waters rose for seven days...
- Kamchadale (northeast Siberia): A flood covered the whole land in the early days of the world...
- [Mongolia:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Hailibu, a kind and generous hunter, saved a white snake from a crane which attacked it...
- [Hindu:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Manu, the first human, found a small fish in his washwater...
- [Bhil (central India):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Out of gratitude for the dhobi feeding it, a fish told a dhobi (a pious man) that a great deluge was coming...
- [Kamar (Raipur District, Central India):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A boy and girl were born to the first man and woman. God sent a deluge to destroy a jackal which had angered him...
- [Tibet:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Tibet was almost totally inundated, until the god Gya took compassion on the survivors, drew off the waters through Bengal...
- [Jino (southern Yunnan, China, near Mekong R.):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) From the time of creation, people's lives were happy and peaceful, but one year a great flood came...
- [Karen (Burma):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Two brothers survived a world-wide deluge on a raft...
- [China:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The Supreme Sovereign ordered the water god Gong Gong to create a flood as punishment and warning for human misbehavior...
- [Korea:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A son was borne to a fairy and a laurel tree; the fairy returned to heaven when the boy was seven years old...
- [Batak (Sumatra):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The earth once rested on the three horns of the giant snake Naga Padoha, who grew tired of its burden and shook it off into the sea...

**Australia**

- [Arnhem Land (northern Northern Territory):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) In one version of the myth of the Wawalik sisters, the sisters, with their two infant children, camped by the Mirrirmina waterhole...
- [Maung (Goulburn Islands, Arnhem Land):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) People dividing fish always gave the man Crow the poor quality ones...
- [Maori (New Zealand):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Long ago, there were a great many different tribes, and they quarrelled and made war on each other...

**Pacific Islands**

- [Kabadi (New Guinea):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Lohero and his brother were angry with their neighbors, so they put a human bone into a small stream...
- [Papua New Guinea:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) A flood covered the whole world except for the summit of Mount Tauga...
- [Fiji:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The great god Ndengei had a favorite bird, called Turukawa, which would wake him every morning...
- [Samoa:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) In a battle between Fire and Water...
- [Mangaia (Cook Islands):](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) The rain god Aokeu ("Red Circle" for the red clay he washes around the island), who was lowly born of the drippings from stalactites, disputed with the ocean god Ake to see which was more powerful...
- [Tahiti:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Tahiti was destroyed by the sea. Even the trees and stones were carried away by the wind. But two people were saved...
- [Hawaii:](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/flood-myths.html) Lalohona, a woman from the depths of the sea, was enticed ashore by Konikonia with a series of images...